# How do you create Object of Arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I spent more time on this than I would like to admit. I have trouble constructing an object filled with an array.

I would like my data to look like this:

```
items={
    {
     '2012-05-22': [{text: 'item 1 - any js object'}],
     '2012-05-23': [{text: 'item 2 - any js object'}],
     '2012-05-24': [],
     '2012-05-25': [{text: 'item 3 - any js object'},{text: 'any js object'}],
    }
}
```

I am making a database call and the data I receive looks like this:

```
Object {start: "08:00:00", end: "09:00:00", full_name: "Tomomi", date: "2017-06-08", Barber_id: "1"…}
```

The data I am interested in is the full_name value and the date value.

This is what I have attempted:

```
let  newItems = {};
axios.post(endpoint, {lookup: day.dateString}).then((customerData) => {
    customerData.data.forEach((val,key)=>{
        newItems = {[val.date]:[]};
        newItems[val.date].push({name:val.full_name});
        console.log(newItems); 
    })
}
```

It looks like this:

```
Object {2017-06-08: Array(1)}
2017-06-08
:
Array(1)
```

This is very close, but the problem is that my code is overwriting my data.
I am trying to create this dynamically:

```
'2012-05-25': [{text: 'item 3 - any js object'},{text: 'any js object'}],
```

So that each date can have many users. Hopefully, this makes sense.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: First of, why `items = {{}}` ? Should be like `items = {}`

Comment: How do you call `.forEach()` on an object without an error? What is `customerData.data`, an array or an object?

Comment: Also, from the result you're looking for - seems you're not actually interested at all in `full_name`

Comment: I am trying to push the value of the customer into the object. with this line:newItems[val.date].push({name:val.full_name})

Comment: @guest271314 it's an array from mysql database.

Comment: Does each object have a unique `"date"` property value?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan The API used that as an example.

Comment: @guest271314. Yes, each object has a unique date property value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var byDate = {}; // Object to store received data by-date

function addIntoByDate( obj ) {
  byDate[obj.date] = byDate[obj.date] || [];
  byDate[obj.date].push( obj );
}

// Simulate adding server data one by one
addIntoByDate( {date: "2017-06-08", full_name: "Cat", text:"Foo!!"}  ); // < SAME DATE
addIntoByDate( {date: "2016-05-23", full_name: "Dog", text:"Bar"}    );
addIntoByDate( {date: "2017-06-08", full_name: "Bug", text:"Baz..."} ); // < SAME DATE

// test
console.dir(byDate);
```

Answer (score 2):

The function expression you pass to forEach has this as the first line:

```
newItems = {[val.date]:[]};
```

This resets the newItems object to an object with one date:name pair.  You really want something more like:

```
newItems[val.date]?newItems[val.date].push({name:val.full_name}):newItems[val.date]=[];
```

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use object destructuring, computed property and `Object.assign()`

```js
const newItems = {};

const data = [
               {
                 start: "08:00:00"
               , end: "09:00:00"
               , full_name: "Tomomi"
               , date: "2017-06-08"
               , Barber_id: "1"
               }
             ];

data.forEach(({date, full_name}) => 
  Object.assign(newItems, {[date]: [{/* text: */ full_name}]}));
  
console.log(newItems);
```

Comment: I totally forgot about Object.assign this was helpful, but Roko's answer worked a bit better for me.